# About php7 Uniform Variable Syntax, nested functions

Tags: php, anonymous-function, currying

I'm try to solve a task which uses new functions php7 uniform variable syntax  nested () support `foo()()` (https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax).
I need write function test for this code:

```
$sum = function($a, $b)  { return $a + $b; };
test(6)(2)(3)($sum);    // 11
test(3)(1)($sum);       // 4
test(3)(3)('pow');      // 27
```

I don't found any explanation for this feature. Where can I find how to use it? I see that I must return function name in function test, but how to pass argument?

Comment: The thing in this way of writing is to have something like an accumulator and use it.

Comment: I think in that case:

function test($a) {
 var_dump($a);
 return 'test';
}

But how to pass variable to function, that I return? Should I use global variables? Probably, that's bad idea.

Comment: No no. You can pass anonymous functions! `return function () {}`.

Comment: Your `test` function needs to check the type of its argument. If it's a number, it has to return a function that curries the argument. If it's a function, it calls `array_reduce($function, $arguments)` where `$arguments` is all the curried arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for help. It's something like this:

```
<?php

function test($a) {
    echo '<br/>';
    $arr[] = $a;
    return $mf = function($b) use(&$mf, &$a, &$arr) {
        if(gettype($b) == 'object') {
            echo(array_reduce($arr, $b));
        } elseif (gettype($b) == 'string') {
            if($b == 'pow') {
                echo array_reduce($arr, function ($carry, $a) {
                    return !empty($carry) ? pow($carry, $a) : $a;
                });
            }
        } elseif (gettype($b) == 'integer') {
            $arr[] = $b;
        }
        return $mf;
    };
}

$sum = function($a, $b)  { return $a + $b; };
test(6)(2)(3)($sum);    // 11
test(3)(1)($sum);       // 4
test(3)(3)('pow');      // 27
```

Comment: I wouldn't hard code any details about pow, that kind of limits this function.

Answer (score 0):

This is more about nested recursive functions, or currying, than that rfc.  That rfc just enabled the syntax that supported it.

This uses recursion until you pass a callable:

```
function test($var) {
    $values = [$var];
    $function = function($callback) use (&$values, &$function) {
        if (is_callable($callback)) {
            return array_reduce(array_slice($values, 1), $callback, $values[0]);
        }
        $values[] = $callback;
        return $function;
    };
    return $function;
}
```

Because your functions expect two parameters but your nesting could have unlimited parameters, it's best to use an array and array reduce.

However, since multiplication functions like pow won't work with a null initial value, you can specify the initial value as the first passed parameter from the array.